# Why does MethodImplOptions.Synchronized cause a lock on this when that is not recommended?

Tags: c#, .net

I was looking at the available values of the [MethodImplOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx) enumeration when I noticed the following:

> Locking on the instance or on the type, as with the Synchronized flag, is not recommended for public types, because code other than your own can take locks on public types and instances. This might cause deadlocks or other synchronization problems.

So I am wondering why the compiler (or is this done by the .Net runtime?) does this instead of creating a private field and lock on that instead?

It sounds like a simple fix, but I suppose it isn't...

Comment: It's perfectly safe (bar the usual multithreading madness) to use on non-public types. Just like it says in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but using a private field would make it safe with public types as well. And I don't think that would cause any problems.

Comment: This lets you go wild and mix and match the `Synchronized` flag with `lock` statements. Hmm, maybe that's not an argument in favor of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by the CLR - if it were done by the compiler, it wouldn't require an attribute.

It's possible it's there to make it easier to run Java code... either that, or it was just a mistake propagated from the Java mindset :(

(The fact that every object can have a monitor associated with it is a mistake to start with, IMO... again, copied from Java basically.)

Comment: It sounds too obvious to be a mistake. After all the problem is well known and even noted in the documentation. But how does it make running Java code easier? Is it common to lock on this there?

Comment: @Rune: In Java, you can declare synchronized methods. I don't know offhand whether they're implemented by a method flag or by the compiler doing stuff, but if it's as a method flag, that's the equivalent to the interface. Just because the problem is well-known and documented *now* doesn't mean it wasn't a mistake *back then*.

Comment: Good point. I don't think locking on a private field as compared to locking on this would cause any problems though. So is there any reason not to do that?

Comment: @Rune: Well, it adds an extra object to be created, and an extra field within the type... and it doesn't allow you to lock on the same object externally in the rare cases you really *want* to. Basically, I think this attribute value is a bad idea. Simply avoid, and do the locking explicitly.